# Responding with an html page for request mapping

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, jakarta-ee

I am setting up and Rest Endpoint for "/home" mapping . How can I return a webpage(.HTML).

I have tried with response redirect, but seemed it didnt pick the file to redirect.

```
@RequestMapping("/home")
     public ReturnType welcome() {
        return "First\src\main\resources\static\home.html";
    }

NOTE : ReturnType here is mentioned ,as unbale to decide on return type
```

I need to return an home.html placed at (First\src\main\resources\static\home.html) as response for request mapping "/home"

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to stream content directly.

```
     @RequestMapping("/home")
     public InputStreamResource welcome(ServletResponse output) {
         intput=this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("static\home.html");
         return new InputStreamResource(inputStream);
    }
```

You might need to set some response headers if content sniffing is disabled.